# sql query runs in shell but not via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME as name,
       TABLE_NAME as parent_table,
       COLUMN_NAME as parent_column,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referenced_table, 
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referenced_column 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
where table_schema = 'schema_name' 
  and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
```

It returns the expected result on the mysql shell but returns an empty list when run with sqlalchemy.

The sqlalchemy engine has the same user credentials as the shell.
Every other query I've tried, gives the same result via sqlalchemy as it does on the shell. Sqlalchemy version is 1.3.19

Here's a sample of the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

def get_references_query(schema_name: str):
    references_query = """SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME as name,TABLE_NAME as parent_table,COLUMN_NAME as parent_column,
                        REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as referenced_table, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as referenced_column
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where table_schema = '""" + schema_name + """'
                        and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null"""
    return references_query


def connect_to_source(type_, user, password, host, port, db):
    """Returns a sqlalchemy engine"""
    if type_ == 'mysql':
        driver = 'pymysql'
    elif type_ == 'postgresql':
        driver = 'psycopg2'
    return create_engine(f'{type_}+{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}', echo=True)


engine = connect_to_source(db_type, username, password, host, port, db)
conn = engine.connect()
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(conn)

query = get_references_query(insp.default_schema_name)
resultproxy = conn.execute(query)
```

My db is mysql. The query construction logic is fine as far as I can see. The query being echoed when run on the shell, gives the right output.

Comment: Can you share the sqlalchemy code used to invoke the query as a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: added the code sample

Comment: Works for me. I am using driver mysqldb though. Actually works with the pymysql driver too.

Comment: Have you tried printing the results? for i in resultproxy: print(i)

Comment: Of course. Prints nothing.